# ASP.NET Swagger IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, swagger

In Swagger UI I get a model like:

```
Inline Model [
    Inline Model 1
]
Inline Model 1 {
    Id (string, optional),
    ConnectionString (string, optional),
    ConnectionState (string, optional)
}
```

for a REST Get method like:

```
public IEnumerable<Device> Get()
{
    return new List<Device>();
}
```

Why is it not displayed correctly?

*Adding Swagger Config from comments*

```
public class SwaggerConfig 
{ 
    public static void Register() 
    { 
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly; 
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration .EnableSwagger(c => { c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "api"); }) .EnableSwaggerUi(c => { }); 
    } 
} 

public class Device 
{ 
    public string Id { get; set; } 
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; } 
    public string ConnectionState { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example how it should be displayed? Alternatively you can try to specify the response type with the `ResponseTypeAttribute` and check if it changes how it's displayed.

Comment: Should be something like: [
    Device
]
Device {
    Id (string, optional),
    ConnectionString (string, optional),
    ConnectionState (string, optional)
}

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem with a new created Web API Project and installed swagger, the result was like desired. Can you post your Swagger configuration? Also can you tell me if `Device`is defined by you or is from another assembly?

Comment: public class SwaggerConfig
{
 public static void Register()
 {
  var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
   .EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
     c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "api");
    })
   .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
    {
    });
 }
}



public class Device
{
 public string Id { get; set; }
 public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
 public string ConnectionState { get; set; }
}

Comment: So, has nobody else tried to return IEnumerable<> or IList<> with Swagger before?

Answer (score 4):

In C# Asp.Net web api, I did this:

1- In SwaggerConfig.cs

```
              .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {//add this line
                 c.SchemaFilter<ApplyModelNameFilter>();
                }
```

2- add a class that implements ISchemaFilter:

```
class ApplyModelNameFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
    {     
        schema.title = type.Name;
    }
}
```

I got the idea from [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/179)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Swagger and/or NSwag do not handle Generic List/IList/IEnumerable types very well as a base type, perhaps because some frameworks that may try to connect with Swagger don't understand them.

I have worked around this by wrapping my List in another object. So, in your case, you may need to do something like:

```
public ListResponseObject<T>()
{
    public IEnumerable<T> ResponseList {get; set;}
}
```

And then return from your controller like this:

```
public ListResponseObject<Device> Get()
{
    return new ListResponseObject<Device>{ResponseList = new List<Device>()};
}
```

Not as simple... but should get it through Swagger better.

We've leveraged this to our advantage. We've applied this technique to all controllers (or something similar) so we have a more standardized response. We can also do this:

```
public ListResponseObject<T>() : ResponseObject<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> ResponseList {get; set;}
}


public ResponseObject<T>()
{
    public string Message {get; set;}
    public string Status {get; set;}
}
```

And now you have a container that will make downstream handling a little easier.

Not an exact answer, but a work-around that's worked for us. YMMV

***UPDATE:*** Here's a response to a question I posted in the NSwag GitHub [issues](https://github.com/NSwag/NSwag/issues/370):

> I think its correct as is. Currently swagger and json schema do not support generics (only for arrays) and thus all generic types are expanded to non-generic/specific types... altough the models should be correct but you may end up with lots of classes...

An enhancement for supporting generics is planned but this will be not compliant with swagger and only work with nswag... (No support in swagger ui)